# Doctrine Paginator Iteration is an array of 1 object

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, pagination, dql

I'm trying to use doctrines Paginate class to fetch some tasks.

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('DISTINCT task, priority, company, invoice')
            ->addSelect('priority.id as priority_id')
            ->from('TekniqSD4Bundle:task', 'task')
            ->leftJoin('task.slips', 'slips')
            ->leftJoin('task.comments', 'comments')
            ->leftJoin('task.files', 'files')
            ->leftJoin('task.steps', 'steps')
            ->leftJoin('task.status', 'status')
            ->join('task.invoice', 'invoice')
            ->join('task.priority', 'priority')
            ->join('invoice.company', 'company');

$query = $qb->getQuery()
            ->setMaxResults(2)  
            ->setFirstResult($offset);
$paginator = new Paginator($query, true);
foreach($paginator as $task){
    var_dump($task); //this spits out an array containing 1 task
}
```

My question is, why is $task an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selected `priority.id` in your DQL is causing this problem, since the ORM has to retrieve it as scalar result. Accessing `$task[0]` should give you [fetch-joined](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins) `task` object, while `$task['priority_id']` gives you the scalar representing `priority.id`.